# Glide - Different rounded corners in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I try to load a bunch of images into RecyclerView with the help of Glide library (4.9.0).
My code for this is like:
ViewHolder

```
inner class HorizontalImageViewHolder(v: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(v) {
    fun bind(item: SliderImage) {
        val url = (item.icon as UrlIcon).url
        Glide.with(itemView)
            .load(url)
            .transform(RoundedCorners(40))
            .into(itemView.ivImage)
    }
}
```

layout

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@color/orangey_yellow"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/slider_image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/slider_image_height">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@tools:sample/backgrounds/scenic[17]" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

setData

```
fun setData(items: List<SliderImage>) {
    data.clear()
    data.addAll(items)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

But when I scroll items, I see they have different rounded corners size like this

[image]

Does anyone know what's the problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the way.

The problem was in different images resolutions.
So before rounding images corners with glide and expecting roundings to be visually equal, override resolutions to be equal too.

I did this like

```
    val transformations = mutableListOf<Transformation<Bitmap>>(CenterCrop())
    if (cornerRadius > 0) transformations.add(RoundedCorners(cornerRadius))
    //other transformations here

    Glide.with(iv)
        .load(url)
        .apply {
            if (width > 0 && height > 0) {
                this.override(width, height)//this one u need before applying transforamtions to make sure roundings will look equal
            }
            this.transform(*transformations.toTypedArray())
        }
        .into(iv)
```

Comment: What is 'width' and 'height' here? Where are they came from?